# Similar adjectives to "worth"

Tags: adjectives, noun-phrases, complements, worth, measure-phrases

> This laptop is worth $140.

Here *worth* does not need a following preposition.  However, when I say, for example:

> I am curious about his motivation behind his decision.

The word *curious* is an adjective and I have to have a preposition *about* afterwards.  My question is :

Are there similar adjectives to *worth* in this respect?

Comment: Good question. _Worth_ is a very unusual word; it seems to be midway between a preposition and an adjective. Words from the Commercial Transaction Frame all have interesting and unusual meaning and usage. For instance, consider [_value, worth, cost,_ and _price_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf).

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600416/2085).

Answer (score 6):

*Worth* is a member of a class of adjectives known as [*transitive adjectives*](https://books.google.de/books?id=rcT62Lpcoc8C&pg=PA284&lpg=PA284&dq=%22transitive+adjective%22+examples&source=bl&ots=jvrAyAb84K&sig=ndpyZ-ZwE0fTzAC_7aTTx-5Gl38&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwigyLqHlqbbAhVGyKYKHWOvDlk4ChDoATACegQIAxAB#v=onepage&q=%22transitive%20adjective%22%20examples&f=false): those that require or permit a complement. Such complements are often prepositional phrases (*proud of, delighted with, successful at*) or infinitives (*eager/reluctant/important to do something*). A very limited number of adjectives in this class take a noun phrase as a complement:

> The pass is [*valid*](https://books.google.de/books?id=w6zguqsU7x0C&pg=PA730&dq=%22valid+two+months%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim1Pf7oqbbAhXQC-wKHWj7D5EQ6AEIMDAC) two months, and a special 20-kilogram baggage allowance is included. — David Stanley, *South Pacific Handbook*, 2000, 270.
>
> I would always say that I was always [*short*](https://books.google.de/books?id=mrdsCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT93&dq=%22short+five+dollars%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAkNOspabbAhVD6qQKHeM5BWMQ6AEIKTAB) five dollars when it should be nickels and dimes. — Brasford Love, *My Life: The Journey to Here*, 2015.

With quantified amounts, *short* may also follow the noun phrase: [*five dollars short*](https://books.google.de/books?id=ddyEjQ9syvcC&pg=PA212&dq=%22five+dollars+short%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK7tyBrKbbAhVPyKQKHYFhCCsQ6AEIKTAB), but always [*short the necessary funds*](https://lparchive.org/Sims-3/Update%2010/).

An investor can also be *long* or *short* a stock:

> For example, when someone buys a stock, he is [*long*](https://financetrain.com/long-and-short-positions-in-financial-assets/) a stock. A long position holder benefits when the price of the asset appreciates as he can sell it at a higher price.

*Worth* is unique in the variety of complements it may take:

> In short, many fraud cases involve losses on such a small scale that it is not [*worth the effort*](https://books.google.de/books?id=XXFTOk-Krg4C&pg=PT234&dq=%22not+worth+the+effort%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGnebppabbAhVKyqQKHT1FDncQ6AEIUzAI) of installing controls to ensure that it does not happen. — Steven M. Bragg, *The Essential Controller*, 2012.
>
> I couldn’t imagine a Saturday without “U”
> For it would be incomplete
> Not [*worth being placed on my calendar*](https://books.google.de/books?id=7SEdDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA26&dq=%22not+worth+my+time%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjigPaZp6bbAhVC_KQKHemLBQAQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22not%20worth%20my%20time%22&f=false)
> Not *worth my time*
> Not *worth the breath I breathe*
> Not worth *anything*.  — Cortez Jordan, “Dominique,”  *Words, Words, Time*, 2012, 26.

In his [Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3096), Geoffrey Pullum lists a new pair of antonymic transitive adjectives in investment jargon:

> UBS says it is cautious on banks globally, and is *underweight* European and Japanese banks and neutral on U.S. banks. The broker is *overweight* Canadian and emerging market banks.

*Overweight* means overinvested in a firm, sector, currency, etc., while *underweight* means the opposite.

A reader commented that carpenters say a board is *proud a sixteenth*, meaning that the board is a sixteenth of an inch too long and thus must — literally — be cut down to size.

Another reader noted the slang usage *I’m good x dollars*, meaning x dollars more than needed.

As you see, *worth* is not the only adjective that can take a noun phrase complement, but it is by far the most common to do so.

Comment: Many "intransitive adjectives" take complements - just not noun phrases, exactly like intransitive verbs.

Comment: @Araucaria: I prefer Trask's categorization so that adjectives with an NP complement are a subclass rather than complete anomalies.

Answer (score 5):

Adjectives most often take preposition phrases, or clauses as Complements. However, very few of them can take noun phrase Complements. There are, nonetheless, four common adjectives that are traditionally recognised to take noun phrase Complements: *like, unlike, worth*, and *due*.

- John is very like [his father]
- It was unlike [anything I had ever seen]
- It's not worth [ten poundds]
- We are due [twenty hour of overtime]

These adjectives are sometimes known as *transitive adjectives* after Fowler because, like transitive verbs, they don't require a preposition before the noun phrase.

In American English the adjective *short* can also be transitive, in which case it often takes a measure phrase as a Complement:

- We were short [two guests]

In British English, *two guests* would be more likely to appear as a modifier:

- We were two guests short

There are other adjectives relating to the world of commerce which take noun phrase Complements. Geoffrey Pullum discusses some of these here: [New transitive adjectives](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3096).

---

<sup>Most of this information can be found in *The Cambridge grammar of the English language*, by Huddleston & Pullum (2002, p546).</sup>